# Difference between RenjinScriptEngineFactory and AppEngineContextFactory

Tags: java, renjin

I am playing around with the excellent [renjin](http://www.renjin.org/) project and I was wondering what the difference is between:

```
RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
```

and

```
ScriptEngine engine = AppEngineContextFactory.createScriptEngine(context);
```

The first example comes from the [eclipse-dynamic-web-project](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin-examples/blob/master/eclipse-dynamic-web-project/src/org/renjin/example/RenjinServlet.java) and the second example comes from the [appengine-servlet](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin-examples/blob/master/appengine-servlet/src/main/java/org/renjin/example/appengine/RenjinServlet.java) example.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both interfaces are wrappers around the SessionBuilder class, which create a new Renjin Session object in which code can be evaluated.

RenjinScriptEngineFactory, which is the implementation for the Java Scripting API, creates a new Session with the vanilla defaults:

```
@Override
public RenjinScriptEngine getScriptEngine() {
   Session session = new SessionBuilder().withDefaultPackages().build()
   return new RenjinScriptEngine(this, session);
}
```

[AppEngineContextFactory](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/blob/master/appengine/src/main/java/org/renjin/appengine/AppEngineContextFactory.java) also creates a new Session, but with an Apache VFS FileSystemManager instance that's compatible with AppEngine:

```
public static ScriptEngine createScriptEngine(ServletContext servletContext) {
    Session session = new SessionBuilder()
        .withFileSystemManager(createAppEngineFileSystemManager(servletContext))
        .withDefaultPackages()
        .build();
    RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();

    return factory.getScriptEngine(session);
}
```

In the AppEngine environment, file system operations are by design quite limited, and allowing an R script to even *try* to access a file on the root, like "/home/alex/mydata" can get your VM shutdown.

For just this kind of scenario, Renjin mediates all R file system operations through the [Apache Virtual File System](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) library, so that you can control how R scripts see and interact with the file system. `AppEngineContextFactory` creates a ["fake" file system](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/blob/master/appengine/src/main/java/org/renjin/appengine/AppEngineLocalFilesSystemProvider.java) in which your web application is at the root.

In this way, your scripts can still safely access files deployed with your application, for example:

```
myModel <- readRDS("/WEB-INF/data/model.rds")
y <- predict(myModel, x)
```

You can of course use [AppEngineContextFactory](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/blob/master/appengine/src/main/java/org/renjin/appengine/AppEngineContextFactory.java) as a starting point to further refine the environment in which your R scripts run.